# Calculate monthly hours

Tags: sql-server, database-design

```
CREATE TABLE EmpAttendance
(
EmpCode INT,
Time_In Time(5),
Time_Out Time(5),
DayDate date
)

INSERT INTO EmpAttendance VALUES (23, '08:30', '13:00', '2018-07-12');
INSERT INTO EmpAttendance VALUES (23, '13:45', '18:30', '2018-07-12');
INSERT INTO EmpAttendance VALUES (23, '09:15', '12:50', '2018-07-13');
INSERT INTO EmpAttendance VALUES (23, '14:02', '18:22', '2018-07-13');
INSERT INTO EmpAttendance VALUES (23, '08:30', '16:00', '2018-07-14');
INSERT INTO EmpAttendance VALUES (23, '08:45', '17:56', '2018-07-15');
INSERT INTO EmpAttendance VALUES (12, '09:15', '12:50', '2018-07-13');
INSERT INTO EmpAttendance VALUES (12, '14:02', '18:22', '2018-07-13');
INSERT INTO EmpAttendance VALUES (12, '08:30', '16:00', '2018-07-14');
```

I have this table structure that is storing the time in and out of specific employee on a specific day. I want to calculate the total number of hours that an employee was present for a whole month.

The query should accept 2 input date parameters and employee code and give the output as total hours.
I am able to get daily hours but I want to calculate monthly as well and can't figure out how.

```
SELECT EmpCode, [DayDate],
FirstIN    = CAST(MIN(Time_In) AS TIME), 
LastOUT    = CAST(MAX(Time_Out) AS TIME), 
HoursSpent = DATEDIFF(HOUR, CAST(MIN(Time_In) AS TIME), CAST(MAX(Time_Out) AS TIME)),
CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), Datediff(second, CAST(MIN(Time_In) AS TIME), CAST(MAX(Time_Out) AS TIME))/3600) 
       + ':' 
       + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (Datediff(second, CAST(MIN(Time_In) AS TIME), CAST(MAX(Time_Out) AS TIME)) % 3600) / 60), 2) 
       + ':' 
       + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Datediff(second, CAST(MIN(Time_In) AS TIME), CAST(MAX(Time_Out) AS TIME)) % 60) , 2 ) 

       AS hoursSpent
FROM EmpAttendance
GROUP BY EmpCode, DayDate
```

Comment: You could add a computed column like the following `DATEDIFF(HOUR, '01.01.1900', DATEADD(DAY, CASE WHEN @TimeOut < @TimeIn THEN 1 ELSE 0 END , CAST(@TimeOut as datetime) - CAST(@TimeIn as datetime)))` and get the full hours per row as an integer. If you need it to be precise to the minute, add it with `MINUTES` as the interval. If you can't change the source table you might want to create a view.

Answer (score 1):

just change it to GROUP BY `DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DayDate), 0)`

```
SELECT  EmpCode, 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DayDate), 0) as MonthDate,
    --FirstIN    = CAST(MIN(Time_In) AS TIME), 
    --LastOUT    = CAST(MAX(Time_Out) AS TIME), 
    HoursSpent = DATEDIFF(HOUR, CAST(MIN(Time_In) AS TIME), CAST(MAX(Time_Out) AS TIME)),
CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), Datediff(second, CAST(MIN(Time_In) AS TIME), CAST(MAX(Time_Out) AS TIME))/3600) 
       + ':' 
       + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), (Datediff(second, CAST(MIN(Time_In) AS TIME), CAST(MAX(Time_Out) AS TIME)) % 3600) / 60), 2) 
       + ':' 
       + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Datediff(second, CAST(MIN(Time_In) AS TIME), CAST(MAX(Time_Out) AS TIME)) % 60) , 2 ) 

       AS HoursSpent
FROM    EmpAttendance
-- add the condition here in where clause
WHERE   DayDate >= @StartDate
GROUP BY EmpCode, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DayDate), 0)
```

Comment: I need to pass parameters too. `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`. It's not going to get total hours for all dates this way

Comment: just add a `WHERE` clause to it. example `WHERE DayDate >= @StartDate`

Comment: Can you update and add parameters as well ? I don't need `FirstIn` and `LastOut` columns, just `EmpCode` and `Total Hours` are enough. So that for `EmpCode` 23 `Total Hours` will be around `36:35` and for `EmpCode` 12 `Total Hours` will be around `17:45`

Comment: is it that difficult to remove the unwanted columns and add the where clause yourself ?

Comment: Not the `WHERE` clause, `Parameter`.

Comment: in your case, the parameter goes into the `where` clause as condition to select your required rows

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Time_In` and `Time_Out` values *always* relate to the same day, you can just `sum` up the `datediff` in minutes for each day:

```
declare @t table(EmpCode int
                ,Time_In time(5)
                ,Time_Out time(5)
                ,DayDate date
                );

insert into @t values(23, '08:30', '13:00', '2018-07-12'),(23, '13:45', '18:30', '2018-07-12'),(23, '09:15', '12:50', '2018-07-13'),(23, '14:02', '18:22', '2018-07-13'),(23, '08:30', '16:00', '2018-07-14'),(23, '08:45', '17:56', '2018-07-15'),(12, '09:15', '12:50', '2018-07-13'),(12, '14:02', '18:22', '2018-07-13'),(12, '08:30', '16:00', '2018-07-14');

select EmpCode
        ,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,DayDate),0) as MonthGroup
        ,sum(datediff(minute,Time_In,Time_Out))/60 as HoursWorked
        ,sum(datediff(minute,Time_In,Time_Out))%60 as MinutesWorked
from @t
group by EmpCode
        ,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,DayDate),0)
;
```

Output:

```
+---------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------+
| EmpCode |       MonthGroup        | HoursWorked | MinutesWorked |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------+
|      12 | 2018-07-01 00:00:00.000 |          15 |            25 |
|      23 | 2018-07-01 00:00:00.000 |          33 |            51 |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------+
```